# Without additional Data Structure identify string has unique WORDS

Tags: algorithm

I can identify uniqueness of words in string using additional Data Structures like Hashmap but I'm not able to figure out without additional Data Structures .
Unique characters can be determined by using additional integer or bit set but how words can be fit there ?

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks

Comment: Two nested loops that check all pairs?

Comment: Sort your words, perhaps?